# Python: Grouped constants with possibility to iterate over group

Tags: python

I have a module with constants (data types and other things).

Let's call the module constants.py

Let's pretend it contains the following:

```
# noinspection PyClassHasNoInit
class SimpleTypes:
    INT = 'INT'
    BOOL = 'BOOL'
    DOUBLE = 'DOUBLE'

# noinspection PyClassHasNoInit
class ComplexTypes:
    LIST = 'LIST'
    MAP = 'MAP'
    SET = 'SET'
```

This is pretty and works great, IDEs with inspection will be able to help out by providing suggestions when you code, which is really helpful. PyCharm example below:

[image: IDE Help]

But what if I now have a value of some kind and want to check if it is among the ComplexTypes, without defining them in one more place. Would this be possible?

To clarify even more, I want to be able to do something like:

```
if myVar in constants.ComplexTypeList:
    # do something
```

Which would of course be possible if I made a list "ComplexTypeList" with all the types in the constants module, but then I would have to add potentially new types to two locations each time (both the class and the list), is it possible to do something dynamically?

I want it to work in python 2.7, though suggestions on how to do this in later versions of python is useful knowledge as well.

**SOLUTION COMMENTS:**

I used inspect, as Prune suggested in the marked solution below. I made the list I mentioned above within the constants.py module as:

```
ComplexTypeList = [m[1] for m in inspect.getmembers(ComplexTypes) if not m[0].startswith('_')]
```

With this it is possible to do the example above.

Comment: what is `myVar` in this example? `constants.ComplexType.LIST`, `"LIST"`, an object of type `list`?

Comment: @AdamSmith myVar would be a string, for instance as you say "LIST", which would then be qualified as a constant.ComplexType. That's basically what I want to be able to verify. That an incoming argument is one of the constants in the group.

Comment: darn, that makes my answer wrong. `inspect.getmembers` as @prune answered *might* be the best you can do.

Comment: I did like the suggestion with enum. It would force the caller to specify the "LIST" argument via that enum instead, but it would be really clean and I suggest others to look at enum. For me it is convenient to not have to add more modules to deploy, so that's what draws me towards inspect. Thanks for suggestion though! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I have it.  You can use **inspect.getmembers** to return the items in the module.  Each item is a tuple of (*name*, *value*).  I tried it with the following code.  **dir** gives only the names of the module members; **getmembers** also returns the values.  You can look for the desired value in the second element of each tuple.

constants.py

```
class ComplexTypes:
    LIST_N = 'LIST'
    MAP_N  = 'MAP'
    SET_N  = 'SET'
```

test code

```
from constants import ComplexTypes
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction

print dir(ComplexTypes)

for o in getmembers(ComplexTypes):
    print o
```

output:

```
['LIST_N', 'MAP_N', 'SET_N', '__doc__', '__module__']
('LIST_N', 'LIST')
('MAP_N', 'MAP')
('SET_N', 'SET')
('__doc__', None)
('__module__', 'constants')
```

You can request particular types of objects with the various **is** operators, such as

```
getmembers(ComplexTypes, inspect.isfunction)
```

to get the functions.  Yes, you can remove things with such a simple package.  I don't see a method to get you constants in a positive fashion.  See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html).

Comment: Thank you! Instead of having to import inspect in each module using the constants.py, I could just create the mentioned "ComplexListTypes" list by iterating the values of getmembers(ComplexTypes). It would it always be just '__doc__' and '__module__' I would have to remove from it in such a simple class?

Answer (score 3):

The builtin method .dir(class) will return all the attributes of a class given. Your if statement can therefore be `if myVar in dir(constants.ComplexTypes):`

Comment: Thanks! I need the values as well, but that can be achieved with the inspect module as mentioned below. One concern I had with both inspect and dir was if I was able to know how to cleanly filter the list from all the other stuff that I didn't define myself. But apparently it wouldn't be that much.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood the question correctly, you want to define a custom `type`. You don't really need to import any modules. There are a number of ways you can do this, e.g. meta classes, however, a simple method is as follows:

```
my_type = type('ComplexTypes', (object,), {'LIST': 'LIST'})

var = my_type()
```

Now you can test the type:

```
type(var)
```

which returns:

```
__main__.ComplexTypes
```

In other words:

```
type(var) is my_type
```

which returns `True`

Comment: Thanks! It is actually more constants (quite many too), some of them being types (not for python but for a database, so in another scope) but some also just being plain commands or flags and so on. So it is in general more how to do this with constants. Your answer about types is really useful though in many cases.

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful. You can put this in a loop and create as many types as you need inside a module, and then inherit them by inheriting the aforementioned module. This would additionally optimise your programme, especially if, as you suggested, these are frequent / frequently used. Importing modules, calling their functions and going through a loop each time would inevitably reduce the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Since Python 3.4 ([PEP 435](https://peps.python.org/pep-0435/)), you can group constants with an `Enum` class. An `Enum` class is iterable and hashable. It disallows member reassignment, which means the enum values are truly constant. See this [post](https://realpython.com/python-enum/) for details.

```py
from enum import Enum

class ComplexTypes(Enum):
    LIST = 'LIST'
    MAP = 'MAP'
    SET = 'SET'

# Enum items are iterable
print(f"{list(ComplexTypes)}")

my_type = ComplexTypes.LIST

# Enum items are hashable
print(f"{my_type in ComplexTypes = }")
print(f"{'LIST' in ComplexTypes.__members__ = }")

# Get value of the corresponding enum
val = ComplexTypes.LIST.value
print(f"{val = }")
```

prints

```
[<ComplexTypes.LIST: 'LIST'>, <ComplexTypes.MAP: 'MAP'>, <ComplexTypes.SET: 'SET'>]
my_type in ComplexTypes = True
'LIST' in ComplexTypes.__members__ = True
val = 'LIST'
```